# Google Play Services error. Update Google Play Services. Помогите!

Tags: android, google-play-services

На android 4.2.2(Api 17) не работает Google Play Services.Он просит обновиться.
На версиях старших версиях (Api 23-25) всё хорошо.
Много гуглил,но так ничего и не нашёл.Всё что написано не помогает.
В чём может быть проблема?

build:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "by.ittech.test_chat"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:1.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.github.siyamed:android-shape-imageview:0.9.+@aar'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.0'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}














apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А обновлять вы пробовали? Не либы, а приложение `GooglePlayServuces` на девайсе?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб не пробовал. Я запускаю приложение на emulator.

Comment: @shcherbuk, эмулятор тоже девайс (виртуальный) и в нём сервисы устарели их надо обновлять как и в реальном устройстве

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в том, что Google Play Services на эмуляторе устанавливается на версиях выше 4.2.2 (Api 17). Об этом сказано в [официальной документации](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#ensure_devices_have_the_google_play_services_apk):

> The Android emulator with an AVD that runs the Google APIs platform based on Android 4.2.2 or higher.

Т.е. обновлять там нечего, т.к. сервисы просто не установлены.

Была такая же проблема, но никакие "танцы с бубном" не помогли. Пришлось тестировать на реальном устройстве.

Comment: А почему не использовать Genymotion?

Comment: @Alex78191 потому, что с ним то же самое. Официально на него [можно установить сервисы](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Genymotion-2.0-Emulators-with-Google-Play-support) начиная с версии 4.4 ( API 19). Точнее сказать не найти apk с сервисами для этой версии, те, что в сети - не решают проблемы. Только потеря времени.

Comment: Раньше же можно было и на 4.0 поставить

Comment: @Alex78191 еще раз повторяю - сейчас официально поставить нельзя. Я не отрицаю, что если Вы инди разработчик и готовы убить пару дней на то, чтобы пытаться поставить на 4.0, то возможно это и получится. Но это - как говорится "вилами на воде написано" и в реальных проектов менеджер этого не допустит.

Comment: а если скачать старый образ с уже установленными Play services?

Comment: @Alex78191 в Genymotion образы вообще не содержат Google Play Services, насколько я знаю, т.к. даже на 5.0 приходилось ставить вручную. Может быть на более новых АПИ, что-то сейчас и есть, но ниже 5.1 - вообще ничего не установлено в образах.

Comment: понятно, а образы google?

Comment: @Alex78191 испробовали очень многое, убили много времени, пришли к выводу, что проще использовать реальное устройство :)

Comment: образы google не содержали play services?